# Create custom map (not world map) for navigation

Tags: android, ios, maps, utility

I want to create a custom map (not of any country/state/city) which can be used for navigation. Am looking for any existing tool that can help me do that for both iOS and Android application. The map would not be a earth map but some custom map where I can define the layout and path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answer isn't very clear, but do you search for real-life map resources such as [openstreetmap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) provides? They should have an API to integrate in your app.

Comment: I am not looking for world map or country map. It would be a custom map

Comment: So you are more likely searching for an algorithm to find the optimized route from point A to point B, having a mesh of points and distances? Or probably a web service which allows defining such a mesh and does the path optimization for you?

Comment: Probably [This link's answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28041/path-finding-algorithms) gives you an idea what to do, or what to search for...